# PrimeNg V6 confirmationService in loop

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, primeng

I am trying to call the confirmation service within a loop, but only the last call is being executed. Is there something that I need to change in this?

```
for (let x of y) {
    if (conditionIsMet) {
        this.confirmationService.confirm({
            message: 'Question Text',
            header: 'Confirmation',
            icon: 'fa fa-refresh',
            accept: () => {
                //DO Accept Work
            },
            reject: () => {
                //Do Rejection Work
            }
        });
    } else {
        //Do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  component is a single instance and so each time you push a new instance to the ConfirmationService you are overwriting the previous one.  To call one after the other, you need to add in some way of waiting for one confirmation to be concluded before making your next call.

I did a quick test of this and got it to work by creating a 'confirmationQueue' array and then calling the service recursively like this:

```
this.confirmQueue = [];
for (let x of y) {
    if (conditionIsMet) {
        this.confirmQueue.push(x);
    } else {
        //Do something else
    }
    this.displayNextConfirm();
}

<snip>

private displayNextConfirm(): void {
    if (this.confirmQueue && this.confirmQueue.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let x = this.confirmQueue[0];
            this.confirmQueue = this.confirmQueue.slice(1);
            this.confirmationService.confirm({
                message: 'Question Text',
                header: 'Confirmation',
                icon: 'fa fa-refresh',
                accept: () => {
                    //DO Accept Work
                    this.displayNextConfirm();
                },
                reject: () => {
                    //Do Rejection Work
                    this.displayNextConfirm();
                }
            });
        }, 1);
    }
}
```

(Note that the `setTimeout(() => {...}, 1)` allows the current confirm dialog to clear before the service tries to open the next one.)

Obviously there are other ways to implement this, but the key is to only submit one call to the ConfirmationService at a time and wait for that to complete before submitting the next one.

Comment: Thank you very much, this did work for my issue. I did remove the 1 millisecond wait in my code and everything appears to be working the way I would expect.